# select from table only if the id exist in that table mysql pdo php

Tags: php, mysql, join, pdo

I want to create a select query using join on 3 or more tables. I have 3 tables namely `t1`, `t2`, `t3` and a common column `id` existing in all 3 tables. I want to select the 3 table if the id exists in the table my query is like this.

```
Select * from t1 
inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
inner join t3 on t2.id = t3.id 
where t1.id = 1 and t2.id = 1 and t3.id = 1
```

the query is returning values if the id exists in all the 3 tables. But if it is not in any table example t3 i will not return anything. I am looking for a way that if it does not exist in `t3` it should i proceed to just select from `t1` and `t2`

Answer (score 0):

I think these sql wil helpful to you

```
Select * from t1,t2,t3 
where t1.id = 1 or t2.id = 1 0r t3.id = 1
```

these sql also will useful to you

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE t1.id=1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t2.id=1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t2.id=1
```

Thank you.

Comment: you satisfied my answer can you give a blue tick mark and up vote please.

Comment: are you sure i don't need to use inner join let me try it out if i get the out put i am expecting rest assured i will tick up the answer button

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1 
INNER JOIN t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
LEFT JOIN  t3 on t2.id = t3.id 
WHERE t1.id = 1 AND t2.id = 1 AND (t3.id = NULL OR t3.id = 1)
```

Comment: sir it could be any table i mean if for instance the if is not available in t2 i mean there is no specific order where the id will be messing from a table. Sorry if i cant express it clearly what i am trying to say is i could be missing in t1 or t2 or t3 or even t2 and t3 will not have the id is this possible

Comment: @Pekka : Please post your sample data (just the relevant fields) and the expected result. Your requirements are not clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id= t2.id WHERE t1.id= 1
```

This will return null for `t3` columns if `id` is not present in `t3`

Comment: i dont want to return null i want to return the data from t1 and t2 since they have the id